# Update hook - is it possible to generate success or failure message on operation success?

Tags: hooks

I would like to be clear on how to indicate success (or failure) messages in update hooks, when a step completes successfully (not using &sandbox).

I vaguely remember seing a post on this (probably here) but all the examples I searched for do not show any messages in the update hook.

Comment: Do you mean the message that gets shown for an individual update (usually in a grey box at the bottom of the completion page)? If so you just `return 'Message';` from the update hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7, [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) doesn't need to return anything to make Drupal understand the update was successful; it needs to throw an exception in case of failure, which is what the methods of [`DatabaseSchema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/class/DatabaseSchema/7), such as [`DatabaseSchema::addField()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21schema.inc/function/DatabaseSchema%3A%3AaddField/7), already do. (Those methods are the ones behind functions like [`db_add_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_add_field/7).)

See any of the update hooks used by Drupal core as example. (I removed the code comments just to make the code shorter.)

```
function user_update_7010() {
  db_change_field('users', 'signature_format', 'signature_format', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'not null' => FALSE,
    'description' => 'The {filter_format}.format of the signature.',
  ));

  db_update('users')
    ->fields(array('signature_format' => NULL))
    ->condition('signature', '')
    ->condition('signature_format', 0)
    ->execute();

  $existing_formats = db_query("SELECT format FROM {filter_format}")->fetchCol();
  $default_format = variable_get('filter_default_format', 1);
  db_update('users')
    ->fields(array('signature_format' => $default_format))
    ->isNotNull('signature_format')
    ->condition('signature_format', $existing_formats, 'NOT IN')
    ->execute();
}
```

```
function node_update_7012() {
  if (variable_get('update_d6', FALSE)) {
    db_update('field_config')
      ->fields(array('translatable' => 0))
      ->condition('field_name', 'body')
      ->execute();

    foreach (array('field_data_body', 'field_revision_body') as $table) {
      db_update($table)
        ->fields(array('language' => LANGUAGE_NONE))
        ->execute();
    }

    node_type_cache_reset();
  }
}
```

The only reason for `hook_update_N()` to return a string is changing the message seen in the update page.

```
// user_update_7002
if ($sandbox['user_from'] == $sandbox['user_count']) {
  if ($sandbox['user_not_migrated'] > 0) {
    variable_set('empty_timezone_message', 1);
    drupal_set_message(format_string('Some user time zones have been emptied and need to be set to the correct values. Use the new <a href="@config-url">time zone options</a> to choose whether to remind users at login to set the correct time zone.', array('@config-url' => url('admin/config/regional/settings'))), 'warning');
  }
  return t('Migrated user time zones');
}
```

#### Reference

- [update_do_one()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21update.inc/function/update_do_one/7)